# Using docmute to import separate document as part of proof?

Tags: amsthm

I have a theorem with a long proof. The proof is so long that it's formed from several separate LaTeX files, each of which I need to be able to work on independently. The way I usually do this is with the `docmute` package, which allows each subfile to have its own headers so it can be worked on as a stand-alone document, but then ignores the headers and the `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` commands when `\input`ing the subfile into the main document.

However, this doesn't seem to work inside a `proof` environment. Here's the MWE. First, the main file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{docmute}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
Here is my important proof.
\begin{proof}
\input{proof}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Now the subfile called `proof.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

The error message:

> LaTeX Error: \begin{proof} on input line 8 ended by \end{document}

Suggestions welcome!

Comment: It works in my computer. I use TeXLive 2011.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your MWE works for me with the current version 1.2 of `docmute` (it fails with the older version 1.1).  Maybe updating the package is all you need.